# Set CheckBox Checked based on CheckBoxes of a GroupBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, groupbox

Good Morning
I want to ask something that is related in checkboxes
I have to groups of checkboxes and it looks like this

[image]

My question is How can i check the checkbox `Purchase Requisition` whenever i check any checkbox in Group `Purchase Requisition` and if all of them are uncheck then checkbox `Purchase Requisition` is unchecked.

I have this code and I put this code on all of the checkbox inside Groupbox `Purchase Requisition`

```
  Sub check_Purchase_Req()
        Dim oCtl As Control
        Dim iX As Integer

        For Each oCtl In GroupBox3.Controls
            If TypeName(oCtl) = "CheckBox" And oCtl.Enabled = True Then iX = iX + 1

            If iX > 0 Then
                CheckBox1.Checked = True

            ElseIf CheckBox19.Checked = False And CheckBox20.Checked = False And CheckBox21.Checked = False And CheckBox22.Checked = False And CheckBox23.Checked = False Then

                CheckBox1.Checked = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

but this code doesnt meet what I need

Any help is appreciated TYSM

Comment: What are these CheckBox19 ~ 23, is this checkbox from Requisition?

Comment: yes sir thats true, i mean correct

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if if works. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: I updated the answer. Saw some logic issues when all is unchecked in my code. Try the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, Checkbox1 to Checkbox5 is the assumed named of the Checkboxes inside `Purchase Requisition` group box.

`chkPurchaseRequisition` is also the Checkbox for your Purchase Requistion checkbox

Try this one:

```
 Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _
CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged, CheckBox4.CheckedChanged, CheckBox5.CheckedChanged
    If sender.Checked = True Then
        chkPurchaseRequisition.Checked = True
    Else
        Dim AllUnchecked As Boolean = True
        For Each c As Control In grpboxPurchaseRequisition.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
            If DirectCast(c, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
                AllUnchecked = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If AllUnchecked = True Then
            chkPurchaseRequisition.Checked = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: TYSM sir <3 Really a great help

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!

Comment: A discount at _Classic Savory_ would be better. Joke lang. Hehe

Comment: Sure but not today because Im not yet regular here hehehe

Comment: TYSSSSM looking forward to see you at one of my post here TYSM again

Comment: With Option Strict On this solution won't compile... Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Using linq for such tasks makes life easier:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).ToList() _
             .ForEach(Sub(c) AddHandler c.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckChanged)
End Sub
Private Sub CheckChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    CheckBox1.Checked = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).Any(Function(c) c.Checked)
End Sub
```

In above code, I supposed `GroupBox1` is the right one and `CheckBox1` is the one which you want to check or uncheck based on `CheckBox` controls of `GroupBox1`.

Comment: This should be the answer. Nice Linq usage by the way.

Comment: Welcome, it's always nice to see people using and in the correct way... ;)